# Adding a placeholder to Bootstrap dropdown select

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the `bootstrap dropdown select` to get a list of data to my form.

The code is as below

```js
jQuery(async function () {
  await LocationService.getOnlineLocations();
  let allLocations = LocationService.getAllLocationsAsArray();
  console.log(allLocations);
  $("#bookingFromInput").ready(function () {
    let text = "";
    allLocations.forEach((element) => {
      text += `<option value="${element.name}">${element.name}</option>`;
    });
    console.log(text);
    $("#bookingFromInput").html(text);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select class="form-select" id="bookingFromInput" name="from" aria-label="Default select example" autofocus>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

[image: Image of how the dropdown is viewed]

I'm trying to figure out a way to add the `placeholder="From"` but the placeholder attribute doesn't seem to work.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: If i understood correctly, you just want to write "From Stonehenge"? 
text += `<option value="${element.name}">From ${element.name}</option>`; or was it a default select like <option value="" selected disabled>From</option>

Comment: @Kelvin Hi I'm trying to do the latter where the user will see the value of the dropdown as "From"

Comment: Yeah as the other commented, you can just use the value = '' as i've written

Answer (score 0):

There is no `placeholder` for an HTML `select`. You will have to make **From**, the first `option` or `optgroup`(not recommended here). Common practice is to use it like this.

```
let text = "<option value=''>From</option>";
```

By keeping the `value=''` you can easily ensure that selection is not made by checking `$("#bookingFromInput").val()=== ""`.

Answer (score 0):

**Rather than trying to put "From" in the option text - the semantically correct approach would be to apply a label with that text** - so that the user knows what the select is in context to.

You should always apply relevant labels to your from controls for accessibility and UX best practise. Note the for="" attribute on the label - that ties the label to the form control with that id and allows screen readers to translate that into meaningful structure.

```css
label {display:block; margin-bottom: 4px}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="bookingFromInput">From:</label>
  <select class="form-select" id="bookingFromInput" name="from" aria-label="Booking From Location" autofocus>
      <option>Amsterdam</option>
      <option>Brunswick</option>
      <option>London</option>
      <option selected>Stongehenge</option>
      <option>Sydney</option>  
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//try using select2 [![answer][1]][1]

    $('#bookingFromInput').select2({'placeholder':'From',allowClear: true});

  //empty if options present
  $('#bookingFromInput').empty();
  //add empty value
  $('#bookingFromInput').append('<option value=""></option>');
  //add option list
  
  $('#bookingFromInput').append('<option value="Bengaluru">Bengaluru</option>');
  $('#bookingFromInput').append('<option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>');
  $('#bookingFromInput').append('<option value="NewYork">NewYork</option>');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select id="bookingFromInput" style="width:80%;">
   <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```